# How to handle NULL with ggvis and shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr, ggvis

I'm writing a Shiny app using ggvis. However, I have some problems with handling **NULL** values when I decided that I'll use ggvis (and dplyr) instead of ggplot2. The idea of the app is to load a file, display the columns of the file so the user can select what to plot on X and Y and than to display it with ggvis. My server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(googleVis)
library(reshape2)
library(ggvis)

    options(shiny.maxRequestSize=30*1024^2)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {


  Data <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
    if (input$datatype == "tel") {
      mydata <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, skip=1, header=TRUE, sep=',')
      source("clean_data.r", local=TRUE)  
    }
    info <- list(mydata=mydata, all.names)
    return(info)
  })

  output$chooseX <- renderUI({
    df <- Data()$mydata
    if (is.null(df)) return(NULL)
    items=names(df)
    #names(items)=items
    selectInput("chooseX","Select X axis:",items, items[[117]])
  })

  output$chooseY <- renderUI({
    df <- Data()$mydata
    if (is.null(df)) return(NULL)
    items=names(df)
    selectInput("chooseY","Select Y axis:",items, items[[49]])
  })

  # allows pageability and number of rows setting
  myOptions <- reactive({  
    list(
      page=ifelse(input$pageable==TRUE,'enable','disable'),
      pageSize=input$pagesize
    ) 
  } )

  output$raw <- renderGvis({
    if (is.null(input$file1)) { return() }
    gvisTable(Data()$mydata[,1:50],options=myOptions()) 

  })

  reactive({
    if (is.null(input$file1)) { return(NULL) }
    df <- Data()$mydata
    if(!is.null(input$chooseX)) { x <- paste(as.character(input$chooseX)) }
    if(!is.null(input$chooseX)) { y <- paste(as.character(input$chooseY)) }
    tel <- df %>% ggvis(~x, ~y) %>% layer_lines() %>%
      set_options(width=400, height=600, keep_aspect=TRUE) %>%
      bind_shiny("tel")
  })

  output$caption1 <- renderText( {
    if (is.null(input$file1)) { return() }
    "Cleaned data"
  })

})
```

In the clean_data.R I just perform some operations on the data. The output is

```
structure(list(tel1= c(4.44445, 4.23688, 4.45421, 4.65202, 4.44689, 
6.23443, 7.43101, 7.42124, 4.54701, 4.23688, 4.41758, 4.84493, 
4.55189, 4.45421, 4.337, 4.65202, 4.54945, 4.45177, 4.43956, 
4.34432), tel2= c(3.33089, 3.33089, 3.33334, 3.33334, 3.33089, 
4.12943, 5.45054, 6.64957, 5.23565, 4.27839, 3.72894, 3.52625, 
3.43102, 3.43102, 3.32845, 3.33334, 3.32845, 3.33334, 3.33334, 
3.32845), tel3= c(1.11356, 0.90599, 1.12087, 1.31868, 1.116, 
2.105, 1.98047, 0.77167, -0.688639999999999, -0.0415099999999997, 
0.68864, 1.31868, 1.12087, 1.02319, 1.00855, 1.31868, 1.221, 
1.11843, 1.10622, 1.01587)), .Names = c("tel1", "tel2", "tel2"
), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

In the ui.R I have nothing but a simple `ggvisOutput("tel")`.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Prototype v0.2"),

  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File'),

    radioButtons('datatype', 'Data Type',c('tel'='tel','Corrective Actions'="corrections"), 'tel'),
    tags$head(tags$style(type="text/css",
                         "label.radio { display: inline-block; margin:0 10 0 0;  }",
                         ".radio input[type=\"radio\"] { float: none; }"))
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Data Information",
               h4(textOutput("caption1")),
               checkboxInput(inputId = "pageable", label = "Pageable"),
               conditionalPanel("input.pageable==true",
                                numericInput(inputId = "pagesize",
                                             label = "Pupils per page",value=20,min=1,max=25)),

               htmlOutput("raw"),
               value = 1),
      tabPanel("Tel Data",
               ggvisOutput("tel"))


    )
  )) )
```

Before using ggvis, everything worked perfectly but it seems that ggvis has some problems handling NULL values. I checked https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ggvis/BBTABX01RoQ/1UQMqgysVd0J and https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/issues/333 but I still did not manage to find a workaround. The error message is:

```
Error in UseMethod("rename_") : 
  no applicable method for 'rename_' applied to an object of class "factor"
```

I turned on `options(shiny.trace=TRUE)` and with it I receive:

```
    SEND {"errors":[],"values":{"chooseX":null,"chooseY":null,"chooseY2":null,"caption1":"","y2axis":null,"raw":""},"inputMessages":[]}

SEND {"errors":{"chooseX":{"message":"no applicable method for 'rename_' applied to an object of class \"factor\"","call":"UseMethod(\"rename_\")","type":null},"chooseY":{"message":"no applicable method for 'rename_' applied to an object of class \"factor\"","call":"UseMethod(\"rename_\")","type":null},"chooseY2":{"message":"no applicable method for 'rename_' applied to an object of class \"factor\"","call":"UseMethod(\"rename_\")","type":null},"y2axis":{"message":"no applicable method for 'rename_' applied to an object of class \"factor\"","call":"UseMethod(\"rename_\")","type":null},"raw":{"message":"no applicable method for 'rename_' applied to an object of class \"factor\"","call":"UseMethod(\"rename_\")","type":null}},"values":{"caption1":"Cleaned data"},"inputMessages":[]}
```

Any ideas for a workaround? Thank you very much!

Comment: It is very difficult to see the problem in a shiny program that is not self contained, and you risk that this question will be closed. I suggest that you boil it down to a server.R and ui.R that run, Use some artificial data.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the remark. I included the full source and the data.

Comment: The usual way to test for NULL is to use `length(obj)==0`

Comment: This program does not run.  In my installation, it needs library(googleVis). Please remove all unnecessary stuff;  there is a lot, and uploading is totally irrelevant, so you can replace it by fixed data. If clean_data.r does nothing relevant, remove it up before posting. Note that checking all this required 20 minutes for me, so I give up, and others probably will do too.

Comment: I agree that some of the things are not needed and the lack of googleVis (I'm sorry, I forgot I had global.R where this is stored). However, I can't remove all the file loading and the loading of chooseX and chooseY cause this is essential to reproduce the case as they are NULL initially. Thank you for the feedback, I'm sorry I wasted your time.